# flutter Xcode: fatal error: module 'admob_flutter' not found @import admob_flutter;

Tags: iphone, xcode, flutter, admob, ios-simulator

I am stuck with an Admob problem. I cannot display the application on the emulator. The app works great on Android.

[image]

This is the Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:

[image]

This file is generated automatically.

What can I try to solve this issue?

Comment: I remove admob_flutter:¸^1.0.1 in the dependencies in pubspec.yaml. But still have others problem. I will only set my app for android.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me seemingly at random with whichever package iOS doesn't feel like cooperating with on a particular day.

This has worked for me in the past:

run `flutter clean` in terminal

run `flutter pub get`

navigate to iOS folder `cd ios`

run `pod install`

Sometimes that does it by itself.

Other times I find I've had to delete the entire iOS folder then have recreate it with

`flutter create .`

Then sometimes I would re-create the folder then do all the first steps again before I can build successfully.

If you do that and have Firebase in your app, keep in mind you'll have to re-add your `GoogleService-Info.plist` file via X-Code.